# Javascript - class elements taking on properties of other class elements

Tags: javascript

Below is a code snippet. I'm attempting to affect the class attribute *margin-bottom* based on both size of window and position. I've gotten this to work in all instances of height, width, etc...but for some reason with *margin-bottom*, all classes take on the size of whichever of my javascript functions come last. I'm not sure if that makes sense? Code below:

```
//Javascript
var thisMB = null;
$("#Full").find(".t16").each(function () {
                thisMB = '1.25em';
            });
            $("#Full").find(".t8").each(function () {
                thisMB = '4.4175em';
            });

 $(this).css("margin-bottom", thisMB);

<!--html-->
             <div>      
                  <ul class="tlist">
                        <li class="theTeams t16">1 1upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                        <li class="theTeams t16">1 1upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                        <li class="theTeams t16">3 1 upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                        <li class="theTeams t16">4 1 upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                        <li class="theTeams t16">5 1 upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                        <li class="theTeams t16">6 1 upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="tlist">
                        <li class="theTeams t8">1 upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                        <li class="theTeams t8">3 upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                        <li class="theTeams t8">5 upLeft upLeft upLeft </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
```

Basically, my LI will take on the latter javascript function rather than the one the specific class instance they are found for. So the .t16 should have a margin-bottom of (say) 14 and the .t8 should be 42...they both are 42. If I move the order they are both 14.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var thisMB = null;
$("#Full").find(".t16").each(function () {
    thisMB = '1.25em';   <--- this assigns the same variable over and over again
 });
$("#Full").find(".t8").each(function () {
      thisMB = '4.4175em'; <--- so does this
});

$(this).css("margin-bottom", thisMB);   <--- this sets the element to thisMB = the final value.
```

You are assigning the variable over and over again, but assigning it to "this" outside of the loop. If you want to set the value of the selected element (`this`), it needs to be INSIDE the `each().` loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That worked. I have stared at this for quite a while...thanks for the fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a variable twice, each time with a different value. Basically you're doing this:

```
var thisMB = null;
thisMB = '1.25em';
thisMB = '4.4175em';
```

If you then check the value of thisMB you get the last value set: '4.4175em'.

I think this is what you want:

```
$("#Full .t16").each(function () {
  $(this).css('margin-bottom', '1.25em');
});

$("#Full .t8").each(function () {
  $(this).css('margin-bottom', '4.4175em');
});
```

**UPDATE**

A little shorter:

```
$("#Full .t16").css('margin-bottom', '1.25em');
$("#Full .t8").css('margin-bottom', '4.4175em');
```

Comment: Flauwekeul, thanks for the iput. That's working great. Appreciate it.